# Should adjectives that modify coordinated nouns be plural?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, множественное-число

Online translators seem to only take the gender of the first noun but what if you wanted to mean in the example *one* apple and *one* banana, but *both* are green - could you then pluralize *green*?

*green apple and banana* → *зеленое яблоко и банан*

*green banana and apple* → *зеленый банан и яблоко*

Comment: There are no online translators to Russian that produce even grammatically formally correct text. They mostly produce total garbage (unlike translators to English).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Computer parsing of texts in natural languages is really hard and tricky, do NOT rely on any computer translator ever: even if dictionary used is good, idioms are pretty like to be unrecognised and master-slave relations between words in sentence (what correct grammar term for it?) will be often parsed wrong. There is no way about it currently from technical point of view.
2. Theoretically, "*Зеленое яблоко и банан*" should be translated as "*green apple and (possibly non-green) banana*". If you wish to mark both as green, you should say "*зеленые яблоко и банан*". However, it is impossible disambiguate "*зеленые яблоки и бананы*".

Comment: I think that you mean dependency or syntactic relations between the words.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pluralize *green* in this case and say

> Зеленые яблоко и банан

This is perfectly fine from both grammatical and phonetic points of view.  This is also true when using possessive pronouns:

> Мои кошка и собака
>   My cat and dog

Comment: Since Russian, as far as I know, has no term "grandparent", would "my grandparents" be мои бабушка и дедушка?

Comment: @KCd  it technically has "прародители", yet it seem that meaning of this word has mutated to 'my distant grand...grandparents', so better to say 'бабушка и дедушка'

Comment: @KCd You're absolutely correct.  The right way of saying would be _мои бабушка и дедушка_.